# I'm getting this error : caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required')))")

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis')

ProxyError: (MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /distilbert/distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english/resolve/main/config.json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required')))"), '(Request ID: 8b2b2a12-cfb4-4ed4-945e-91d8ef79b077)')

​

i tried this:
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis')